# Cannot open new SSH connections after a certain amount of time

Tags: networking, openssh, ping, alpine-linux

I have a web server running Alpine linux and OpenSSH. When I power on the server, for about an hour or two I am able to open SSH connections and send commands fine. However, after that, even though the server is up, it does not respond to pings and I cannot SSH in to it. The server is still running, and I can still access the website being served from it. Why does this happen, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Please provide more details, like the error messages of SSH, or something related.

Comment: The error message is `ssh: connect to host <ip> port 22: No route to host`

Comment: You are going to have to check the logs. Could lots of things, a network problem (such as a rogue DHCP server) or a power management issue in your network card (it could be going to sleep after a while). I suggest you rename the issue though, your actual problem is that you are not able to contact the server in any way, not even ping. You might want to add information on the server's network hardware. At the very least the network card controller (as reported by 'lspci'). Do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: I do have physical access to the server. What logs should I check?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of information regarding your network setup, so I'm going to assume you have DHCP of some sort running and your website may be running on a different interface than your ssh service. If this is not the case, please disregard this answer. If you have DHCP running and it assigns your server an address, you could be running a problem where your server gets a new DHCP address assignment after a couple hours. If so, you should try to statically assign your address on the network.

Comment: Both are running on one interface: only one is up. My DHCP expires after an hour, but I set up crontab to renew it, and my router assigns the same address each time.